# two datepickers with knockout, one updates another

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got attached jQuery datepicker with knockout custom bindings handler, and I want to when updating first field to set minDate of second to day after (in case that other date was not set to later date).

```
<label>Check-in:</label>
<input type="date" id="checkIn" data-bind="datepicker: checkIn, datepickerOptions: {
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1
    }" />
<br/>
<br/>

<label>Check-out:</label>
<input type="date" id="checkOut" data-bind="datepicker: checkOut, datepickerOptions: {
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1
    }" />
```

I have setup [fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/juvastyle/mNuEK/)

e.g.
If for checkOut date is selected 28/11/2012 and you for checkIn choose 25/11/2012 there is no need to change checkOut date, only to set minDate of checkOut to 26/11/2012.

But if you choose 29/11/2012 for checkIn, then checkOut needs to update to 30/11/2012

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it is to subscribe to the first date observable property and use that to set the second:

```
self.checkIn.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    $("#checkOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", self.checkIn());
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mNuEK/1/)

Of course, this is not the most elegant solution, since it requires knowing which part of the view relates to the other property. A better solution might be to create another custom binding.

Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.minDate = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        current = $(element).datepicker("option", "minDate", value);
    }        
}
```

Bound like this:

```
<input type="date" id="checkOut" data-bind="{datepicker: checkOut, datepickerOptions: {
minDate: 0,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
firstDay: 1
},
minDate: checkIn}" />
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mNuEK/2/).

Comment: the binding handler works great!... until you try to load the dates into the observables, ie set the value on page load. I'm guessing would need to add an "init" function to the binding handler with some stuff?