# How to link 2 Jquery UI datepickers with Knockout?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker

I want to link a startDatePicker with a endDatePicker, is there a way to link them with Knockout.js ?

When the user selects a new start date, the endDatePicker would be updated setting the minDate as the new start date and regarding if the new date is after its own date it would update the current date as well?

Thanks in advance, I am trying with custom binders, but I can't get anything working.

Answer (score 2):

That code should work, when selecting a minimum date it will then set the minDate of the second datepicker to its value, vice versa for max.

```
$('#min').datepicker({
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#max" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
})

$('#max').datepicker({
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#min" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but is not possible to do it using Knockout.js and its binding features?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subscribe` to subscribe to changes of an observable. Documentation is here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.startDatePicker = ko.observable();
   self.endDatePicker = ko.observable();

   self.startDatePicker.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       // set the value on the other one
   });

   self.endDatePicker.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       // set the value on the other one
   });
};
```

The rest depends on your binding...

Comment: thanks, in the end I just used the old fashion way and use the datepickers directly

Comment: There's a better way. @Matt Burland did a more elegant work here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496605/two-datepickers-with-knockout-one-updates-another)